# How do I use alt + left mouse button + o (any alphanumeric key on the keyboard) with autohotkey?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, autohotkey

I need two hotkeys:
`alt+q+left mouse button` and

```
alt+w+left mouse button
```

Now I have this that is not working

```
$!LButton:: 
IF getkeystate(h)  {
 send mButton down
 KeyWait, LButton
 send mButton up
}

IF getkeystate(o) {
 send rButton down
 KeyWait, LButton
 send rButton up
}

return
```

and this:

```
$!LButton::rbutton
$!LButton up:: send RButton up
```

which works but doesn't work with "w" or "q".

and this:

```
$!LButton::RButton
IF getkeystate(o) {
 send rButton down
 KeyWait, LButton
 send RButton up
}
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example getting alt + left mouse button + q to send text.

```
!LButton::
IF GetKeyState("q", "P")
{
SendInput, hello world
}
Return
```

Comment: thank you, by the way I have some issues in browser on onshape.com in 2D mode using hotkeys for alt+h+leftbutton .It seems it is intercepted by javascript or something after first alt press. is it possible?